# Make a column no background colour if no value

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I want the columns with no value in it to be blank. What should I add to my formula?

[image: annotated screenshot illustrating the desired outcome]

```
{   
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if([$Sovtid_x0020_tekniker_x0020_2] <= @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50')"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your column 2nd and 3rd column in screenshot? Or they all are of type Date & Time?

Comment: They are all Date & time columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your JSON code something like below:

```
{   
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "debugMode": true,
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0, if([$Sovtid_x0020_tekniker_x0020_2] <= @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50'), '')"
    }
}
```

**Note**:

You can use `Number(DateTimeColumn) == 0` to check if the date column is blank or not. This is the major hint, rest you can build the JSON code around it according to your other conditions.

**References**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt work. The fields that should be blank with no background color is now red

Comment: You need to add this code in the 2nd and 3rd column in your screenshot where it is having blank fields. where are you adding this JSON code?

Comment: I'm adding it in all fields. in each column under "Format column".

Comment: I have updated the JSON code in my answer. please try it and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!