# Sharepoint JSON conditional syntax help

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting, conditional

I am trying to make the text say Expired or Current compared to a date column OR stay blank if the date column is blank. So far, I have:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$ExpiryDate]) == '',  '' , if([$ExpiryDate] <= @now, 'Expired', if([$ExpiryDate] > @now, 'Current', '')))"
```

But for whatever reason, the column then shows the ENTIRE formula in the column instead. I have tried several different permutations of the above, including `isblank`, but I just can't seem to get the syntax exactly how SharePoint likes it.

Comment: I took that offending second bracket out, but now it just makes everything not Current to Expired, even if date column is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number(DateTimeColumn) == 0` to check if the date column is blank or not. This is the major hint, rest you can build the JSON code around it according to your other conditions.

So, try something like this:

```
=if(Number([$ExpiryDate]) == 0, '' , if([$ExpiryDate] <= @now, 'Expired', 'Current'))
```

You can find other ways to check if date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

**Reference**:

[Make a column no background colour if no value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275022/make-a-column-no-background-colour-if-no-value/275027#275027)

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I didn't know you could check date columns using Number, that's so helpful.